# How do I run only ordered tests?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 11, I'm facing a complex issue.

I'm using the Unit Test Explorer to run unit-tests. However, it shows both my normal unit tests and my ordered tests, which are basically collections of tests to run in a specific order too.

That doesn't work well for me, because I would love to have the setting "Run tests after build" on. However, as you would expect, what happens is that it runs both all my tests individually *out of order* and then runs my ordered test as shown in the picture below.

[image]

I would really love to be able to run only my ordered tests when the build finishes. I am not interested in third-party plugins/extensions to help me do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a build server, and then configured my build configuration as follows, which will run all tests with the orderedtest file extension:

[image]